# What's the most Perception I need to be able to open all secret doors?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

My understanding is that all secret doors in the game are tied to one of three stats: Might, Magic, or Perception. It appears that if you have enough of the given stat, you'll always succeed on opening it. If you don't have enough, you may fail, and you will take damage for failing. For instance, I tried about 15 times to open the Perception-based secret door in the lighthouse with a score of 14 perception before it finally worked. I have yet to ever fail a might or magic secret door since I've got characters that are basically pumping those stats up to the exclusion of all else.

Given that I've got characters with high Might and Magic stats, but have no ranged attackers in my party, there has been little reason for me to pump up Perception. Still, I'd like to be able to open all secret doors in the game without having to try and fail dozens of times.

What's the maximum Perception I'll need to open every secret door in the game?

Comment: For the record, I know I can temporarily boost Perception with certain spells, but I still need to know what number I'm shooting for.

Comment: I have not completed the game yet but I'm updating this in case anyone else comes looking... I've got one character with 35 perception which has been enough to open every secret door so far, with only a single failure (with the 2nd attempt succeeding). I'm on Act 3.